# Z index stacking issue using Transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day~! Got a code here that should have my arrows perfectly zooming and stacking but unable to. I need to have the images to respond to entire page zooming and minimizing. Everything works fine except the stacking shows up wrong when i use the .effectimage {
-Webkit-transform:scale(1.1);} but I need to use this to have the arrows connected to each other. I need them connected like a train with their pointed head and tails connected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<style>
.effectimage {
-Webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
 }
.effectimage:hover {
    -position: static
   -transform: inherit;
 -transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.36);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.36);
   -o-transform: scale(1.36); 
   transform: scale(1.36);
   transition: all 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.9s;  
 }
</style>
<div>
<img Src="top title image" style="width:100%">
<div style="left:8px; top:47px; position:-webkit-sticky; max-width:200%; 
max-height:200%;">

 <img Src="GreenLeftArrow.png" class="effectfront" style="left:30px; 
   top:180px; width:32.4%;  height:auto;">
 <img Src="YellowMidArrow.png" class="effectfront" style="left:350px;    
   top:180px; width:30.9%; height:auto;">
 <img Src="PowerPinkF2.png" class="effectfront" style="left:810px; 
   top:180px; width:26.08%; height:auto;">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the arrows connected, change your HTML to:

```
<div style="left:8px; top:47px; position:-webkit-sticky; max-width:200%; 
max-height:200%;">

 <img Src="GreenLeftArrow.png" class="effectfront" style="left:30px; 
   top:180px; width:32.4%;  height:auto;"><!--
 --><img Src="YellowMidArrow.png" class="effectfront" style="left:350px;    
   top:180px; width:30.9%; height:auto;"><!--
 --><img Src="PowerPinkF2.png" class="effectfront" style="left:810px; 
   top:180px; width:26.08%; height:auto;">

</div>
```

This removes the space in between the arrows.

More solutions and information: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Thank you for answering ... but my arrows have triangle point faces and their tales have open spaces for triangles increasing their width and height will still provide spaces that's why im using scale to connect them...

Comment: @IronF. In that case, can you give me a link to your site or a JSfiddle, CodePen, or snippet? Thanks.

Comment: @IronF You'll have to update the `src` with 'http". `<img src="http://example.com/image.png" />` You could do this by uploading them to Flickr or somewhere else.

Comment: I am able to have the 3 picture arrows finally thank you.. pls check